# Why is deap multiprocessing method not faster?

Tags: python, algorithm, multiprocessing, deap, genetic

I am using the DEAP framework to run a genetic algorithm and I am trying to speed it up using the multiprocessing module from deap :

```
import multiprocessing

pool = multiprocessing.Pool()
toolbox.register("map", pool.map)
```

I tried running it both under Linux and Windows both from PyCharm and the cmd/terminal, the results were similar. The algorithm always took a few seconds longer than without the multi-processing.

Anyone encountered the same problems and if so were they able to solve it?

Many thanks

Comment: There is inherent overhead to shipping data to/from the distributed places that you're running code.  If that overhead exceeds the parallelism, you will be slower.  Find ways to ship less data, and do more running of code before it returns, and parallelism will become a win.

Comment: Any recommendation on how you would go about monitoring the time it takes to ship the data?

Comment: If you can turn on tracing then look at https://pypi.org/project/flameprof/, the time spent pickling/unpickling is going to be a very large fraction of shipping data.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know your exact scenario. But if you build an algorithm that performs a single sequential work then using multiprocessing might be slower than a regular task. Because it takes time to allocate resorces. Maybe that's your case.

Comment: This was my first impression as well, I guess I will need to monitor the time it takes to allocate those resources in order to find out whether the slowing down of the algo comes from that.